# Grey Bar at bottom of Website Only On Mobile View

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, background-image

I have set a background on my website (www.brentleas.com) and it fills the screen on desktop but on mobile it doesn't. When I use the development tools on chrome it shows the image filling the screen. However when I load up the website on my phone it has a grey bar at the bottom of the page.

Image showing what I'm talking about: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62MUu.png)

Here's my css code:

```
html {

background-image: url("../images/cooper.png");

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-position: center center;

background-attachment: fixed;

background-size: cover;

background-color: #464646;

color: white; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue on Chrome 59 dev tools.

Comment: Does it fill the screen for you when using the developer tools? I'm using chrome 59 as well.

Comment: [Yes](https://preview.ibb.co/fFmhua/Capture.png)

Comment: Do you have a mobile device that you could try loading it up on? On my nexus 6p and galaxy s8 it shows a grey bar.

Comment: Just checked on my phone. It covers the whole screen. Try opening the page in an incognito tab.

Comment: Yep no grey bar in incognito mode... but still there in normal mode.

Comment: That means that your issue is caching. Your phone(s) has / have an old version of your page and it's displayed it instead of downloading the page again. You need to [clear your cache.](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/)

Answer (score 1):

`min-height: 100%;` should do the trick I guess

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I would put html and body on height: 100%; or min-height: 100%;

Answer (score 1):

use js like this and tweak it based on viewport size:

```
//ON LOAD INITIALLY ASSUME PHONE
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.padding = "2px";
var mainItems = doc.getElementsByClassName("main-item");
for (var i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++) {
    mainItems[i].classList.add("full-width");
}
doc.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].classList.add("column");
// doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "none";
if (width >= 840) {
    //IT'S A DESKTOP
    doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.padding = "24px";
    for (var i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++) {
        mainItems[i].classList.remove("full-width");
    }
    doc.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].classList.remove("column");
    // doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
    // doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "flex";
}
else if (width >= 480) {
    //IT'S A TABLET
    // doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "flex";
    doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.padding = "24px";
    for (var i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++) {
        mainItems[i].classList.remove("full-width");
    }
    doc.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].classList.remove("column");
}
//ON RESIZE INITIALLY ASSUME PHONE
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeThrottler, false);
var resizeTimeout;
function actualResizeHandler() {
    // assuming device is a phone
    doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.padding = "2px";
    for (var i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++) {
        mainItems[i].classList.add("full-width");
    }
    doc.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].classList.add("column");
    // doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "flex";
    // doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "none";
    if (window.innerWidth >= 840) {
        //device is a desktop
        doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.padding = "24px";
        for (var i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++) {
            mainItems[i].classList.remove("full-width");
        }
        doc.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].classList.remove("column");
        // doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
        // doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "flex";
    }
    else if (window.innerWidth >= 480) {
        //device is a tablet
        doc.getElementByTagName("body")[0].style.padding = "24px";
        for (var i = 0; i < mainItems.length; i++) {
            mainItems[i].classList.remove("full-width");
        }
        doc.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].classList.remove("column");
        // doc.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
        // doc.getElementById("title-right").style.display = "flex";
    }
}
function resizeThrottler() {
    // ignore resize events as long as an actualResizeHandler execution is in the queue
    if (!resizeTimeout) {
        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            resizeTimeout = null;
            actualResizeHandler();
            // The actualResizeHandler will execute at a rate of 15fps
        }, 66);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cleared the cache on my phone. Now the grey bar is gone.

Comment: This is actually the solution more often than not, if you've already set the height to 100%